# one to one mapping with field acts as both PK & FK value not saving to db with cascade

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
CREATE TABLE `incident` (
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`author_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `adr` (
  `author_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `published` date NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`author_id`),
  KEY `author_fk` (`author_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `author_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`) REFERENCES `incident` (`author_id`)
);
```

Here its a one to one mapping between incident and adr.
In adr table, where author_id is both PK & FK.

How can we create an entity class for this king of one to one relation ship.

**Tried Solution**

//incident table entity class

```
 Entity
    @Table(name="INCIDENT")
    public class Incident implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR_INCIDENTID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="IR_SEQ_INCIDENT_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="IR_TB_INCIDENT_HDR_INCIDENTID_GENERATOR")
        @Column(name="AUTHOR_ID")
        private int authorId;

        @Column(name="NAME")
        private String name;

        @Column(name="EMAIL")
        private String email;

@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,  mappedBy="Incident")
    private Adr  adr;
        /** constructors , getters & sertters **/
        }




    compile time Exception in Incident.java
In attribute 'adr', the "mapped by" attribute 'incident' has an invalid mapping type for this relationship.
```

*How can I define adr entity so that author id will refer to author Id in incident table
    tried this but not working*

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ADR")
public class Adr implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="INCIDENT_ID") 
    private Incident Incident;

    @Column(name="TITLE")
    private String title;

    /** rest of the fields and methos **/
    }
```

Comment: Using `@JoinColumn` and `@OneToOne` on both sides did not help?

Comment: not working.. updated the question